# Why is my React switch not working in this modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I have been trying to build this modal which consists of 4 different steps. 
So I want to load four different files into the modal. When I now load my application and press the button on the first screen, my state does get updated but for some reason my component doesn't update to the second case.

This is the file of the modal:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Checkbox, Radio, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, FormGroup, FormControl, Button, Tabs, Tab } from 'react-bootstrap';

// import AddSparkForm
import AddSparkStep1 from './add-spark-form/add-spark-step-1'; 
import AddSparkStep2 from './add-spark-form/add-spark-step-2'; 
import AddSparkStep3 from './add-spark-form/add-spark-step-3'; 
import AddSparkStep4 from './add-spark-form/add-spark-step-4'; 

export default class AddSparkModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.createSpark = this.createSpark.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeUrl = this.handleChangeUrl.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeContent = this.handleChangeContent.bind(this);
    this.showStep = this.showStep.bind(this);
    this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this);
    this.previousStep = this.previousStep.bind(this);

    this.state ={
      step : 1
    };
  }

  nextStep() {
    this.setState({
      step : this.state.step + 1
    })
  }

  previousStep() {
    this.setState({
      step : this.state.step - 1
    })
  }


  showStep(){
    switch (this.state.step) {
      case 1:
        return <AddSparkStep1 nextStep={this.nextStep}
                              previousStep={this.previousStep} />
      case 2: 
        return <AddSparkStep2 nextStep={this.nextStep}
                              previousStep={this.previousStep}/>
      case 3: 
        return <AddSparkStep3 nextStep={this.nextStep}
                              previousStep={this.previousStep} />
      case 4: 
        return <AddSparkStep4 nextStep={this.nextStep}
                              previousStep={this.previousStep}/> 
    }
  }
  

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="background-container">
        {this.showStep()}
        </div>
    )
  }
```

And this is the file of my first document:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Col, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class AddSparkStep1 extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this);
  }


  nextStep(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('it works till the nextStep');
    this.props.nextStep();


    /* Get values via this.refs
    var data = {
      name     : this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value,
      password : this.refs.password.getDOMNode().value,
      email    : this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value,
    }
    this.props.saveValues(data)
 */
   }
   
  render(){
  return (
   <div>
   <h1>Step 1: What is a spark?</h1>

   <p>some more text</p>

   <Button className="btn -primary pull-right" onClick={this.nextStep}>Save &amp; Continue</Button>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

I hope someone can help me figure this one out.

Kind regards, 
Dominic

Comment: your code looks ok, try this: remove the line and check `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: You're binding several functions in the `constructor` that don't exist in your snippet. Is it possible that function is failing, resulting in `nextStep` and `previousStep` not actually binding?

Comment: Ai ai ai.... It was actually just dumb of me. Everything is working, I just needed to restart my server. 
Thanks for the tip of these functions, I just removed some of the code that was not relevant, these functions are actually in there.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The code above is actually correct, I just needed to restart my server for it to work.

Thanks for the fast replies.